# Difference between K-medoids and PAM

Tags: clustering, k-medoids

I understood that PAM is just one kind of K-medoids algorithm. The difference is in new medoid selection (per iteration):

- K-medoids selects object that is closest to the medoid as a next medoid
- PAM tries out all of the objects in the cluster as a new medoid that will lead to lower SSE.

If I understood well, PAM gives better results, but takes up much more time. Is that so?

Which one is better and why?

---

Here is what confused me, this is a list of software that implements K-medoids, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids)

- ELKI includes several k-means variants, including k-medoids and PAM.
- Julia contains a k-medoid implementation in the Clustering package[5]
- R includes in the "flexclust" package variants of k-means and in the "cluster" package.
- Gap An embrional open source library on distance based clustering.
- Java-ML. Includes a k-medoid implementation.

For example, it says that ELKI contains *both* variants, k-medoids and PAM?

And for example first look on K-medoids implementation in [javaml](http://sourceforge.net/p/java-ml/java-ml-code/ci/e2bee016e81630e062bff7cea88267b6e078eaac/tree/net/sf/javaml/clustering/KMedoids.java#l143) looks like it finds the object closest to medoid and tries it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

k-medoids is the problem specification. It may be a np-hard problem.

PAM is one algorithm to find a local minimum for the k-medoids problem. Maybe not the optimum, but faster than exhaustive search.

PAM is to k-medoids as Lloyd's algorithm is to k-means. Lloyd's algorithm is a fast heuristic to find a good solution to k-means, but it may fail to find the best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But besides of PAM there also exists an original K-medoids algorithm (similar thing with Lloyd's K-means, which everyone calls just K-means), that selects object closest to medoid as next medoid? But PAM is a better solution since it takes less iterations to get to local minimum? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this "original K-medoids"? The original one that I know is PAM...

Comment: I am pretty sure that I saw that version of algorithm somewhere, but I cannot find it at the moment. If I do, I'll share it. Thanks anyway for clarification. :)

Comment: Probably an imprecise statement. Can you find a paper introducing this other k-medians? The javaml approach will *not* work with arbitrary data types or distances. It's more of a k-means with centroids moved to the nearest real data point, but as it uses the centroid, it assumes squared Euclidean distance and a numerical vector space, might just use k-means then...

Comment: I cannot, I'm not sure if I found one, I went through a lot of literature these days, so maybe I just got an impression of it from Wikipedia page. Thanks anyway, I've understood the important thing, K-medoids is a problem, PAM is one of the approaches (algorithms) that can be used to solve it. And when people say K-medoids, they mostly think PAM. :)

Answer (score 1):

A way to look at it found in the literature is that **K-medoids algorithms** is a common name for all algorithms solving an optimization problem of partitioning a set with respect to so called medoids (cluster centers being members of the cluster). Same for K-means algorithms - we can say it's a family of algorithms solving an optimization problem of partitioning a set with respect to so called centroids (cluster means).

The most popular algorithms of K-medoids family (e.g. PAM) and K-means family  apply a similar general approach: iteratively alternating between minimization with respect to cluster centers and minimization with respect to whole partition.